# angularjs sanitize on ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model, html-escape-characters

I use AntiXss Encoder on serverside for XSS atacks so all response includes html unescape characters like **"&lt:script&gt:alert(1);&lt:/script&gt:"** (replaced ';' as ':')

on binding i use sanitize with **ng-bind-html** there is no problem wih that.
There is an other control input for update mode. When user needs to update text they click update icon then i show textarea and hide binded tag with **ng-if**. textarea has **ng-model** attr. i cant escape html characters on textarea like **ng-bind-html** here is the snippet pls help im getting creazy..

in fiddle; edit mode textarea must display "**<script>alert(1);</script>**" with no alert action and data will be sent to the server must display same too...

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bugd67e3/33/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $sanitize) {
    $scope.post1 = "&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;";
    //$scope.post2 = $sce.parseAsHtml("<h1>alert(1)</h1>");
    $scope.logs = ["log created"];
    $scope.log = function(val){
     $scope.logs.push(val);
    }
});
```

```css
.label {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="label">Edit mode :</div>
      <textarea ng-model="post1" style="width:100%;" rows="5"></textarea><br />
      <div class="label">Binding mode :</div>
      <div ng-bind-html="post1"></div><br />
      <div class="label">Data will be send to the server :</div>
      <div>{{post1}}</div><br />
      <div class="label">Logs (if needed) :</div>
      <div ng-repeat="d in logs">
        <p>{{($index+1) + ". " + d}}</p>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the $sanitize service, but it doesn't look like your using it.  This:

`$scope.post1 = "&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;";`

should probably look like this:

`$scope.post1 = $sanitize("&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;";)`

Also, $sanitize is not part of the core Angular package.  If you're not doing so already you'll need to include angular-sanitize.js and add a dependency on the ngSanitize module: 
`var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);`

Comment: i've already using sanitize and used $sanitize nothing happens same :(

Comment: I can also confirm that using the $sanitize module is not working for ng-models